# I am { "error": "consent_required" } while generating the docusign JWT access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

```
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@config[:rsa_private_key])
jwt_payload = { iss: @config[:integration_key],
sub: @config[:user_id], iat: Time.now.to_i,
exp: Time.now.to_i + 3600,
aud: 'account-d.docusign.com',
scope: 'signature' 
}
response = HTTParty.post('https://account-id.docusign./oauth/token', body: { grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', assertion: JWT.encode(jwt_payload, private_key, 'RS256') })
```

I am using the above code with valid credentials to generate the docusign jwt token.
but it giving "consent_required" error.
previously same was working fine. but not working now.

Comment: Believe your scope needs to be "signature impersonation" https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Answer (score 1):

Your Payload is not correct.
and do check your gem file you might have mistakenly removed the JWT gem.

**try this:**

```rb
private_key=OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('path/to/private_key.pem'))
jwt_payload = {
    iss: @config[:integration_key],
    sub: @config[:user_id],
    iat: Time.now.to_i,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 3600,
    aud: 'account-d.docusign.com',
    scope: 'signature'
}
jwt_token = JWT.encode(jwt_payload, private_key, 'RS256')
```

Please note that this code assumes you have the necessary configurations **(@config)** in place and that you have the appropriate private key file for signing the token.

After generating the token, then you can pass it to the API request directly.

Answer (score 0):

- scopes should be "signature impersonation" for JWT
- The correct URL is account-d.docusign.com for authentication
- Even if you do the above right, consent is still required, once pers user/IK combination. Read how to do it in this article - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/

For Ruby code for JWT, I highly suggest you try [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) and pick "Ruby" and "JWT" which will ensure you get a working configured code that just works.